# Разбить на группы данные

Tags: php, post

В php в массиве $_POST есть такие данные

```
["name_1"]=>string(5) "1name"

["val_1"]=>string(6) "1value"

["name_2"]=> string(5) "2name"

["val_2"]=>string(6) "2value"
```

нужно перебрать все значения такого типа(не трогать данные типа $_POST['action'] и др.)

И разбить их на группы: группа со значениями, в которых есть 1 (первая группа), в которых есть 2 (вторая группа)

Как это сделать,

Comment: нужно отправлять данные в нормальной форме, а не костыли делать по перебору `<input name="data[0][name]"/>` и так далее

Comment: @teran те в php получится массив data и с ним уже работать? Спасибо, сам чет не додумался)